# onResumeGame() NullPointerException when using AndEngine

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, andengine

I have an issue with my app when starting an `SimpleBaseGameActivity` from another `SimpleBaseGameActivity`. The code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, PacManActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(INTENT_LEVEL_NUMBER, levelNumber);
intent.putExtra(INTENT_WORLD_NUMBER, worldNumber);
startActivity(intent);
```

It runs good, but when it loads the other `Activity` (`PacManActivity`) it throws an exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onResumeGame(BaseGameActivity.java:220)
at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$4.run(BaseGameActivity.java:371)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm not even implemented `onResumeGame()` method and if I start my `PacManActivity` by default (configured from `Manifest.xml`) it runs without any error.

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Show us BaseGameActivity line 220

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set the following value in your AndroidManifest file for your `Activity`...

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This is a known bug/issue in AndEngine...
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/issues/7

Comment: Adding 'android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout" ' to the Activity node solved the issue. Thanks a lot!